# How to make an item "draggable" in jQuery and how to total up prices in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a draggable online shop. I have created everything except the items on the left can't seem to drag to the "cart" on the right.

The total price also doesn't show up on the cart.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

I have a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/4azrj3uv/

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Draggable</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Annie's Bakery</h1>
        <div id="example-1-2">

            <div class="column left first">
                <ul class="sortable-list list1">
                    <li class="sortable-item" id="dragA"
>
                        <div class="red">Chocolate Chip Cookies <br><a class="more" data-id="dragA" data-price="5.99" name="quantity[0]" value="" placeholder="Quantity">More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level A</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sortable-item" data-id="dragB">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragB">Angel Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragB"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level B</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sortable-item" id="dragC">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragC">Apple Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragC">More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sortable-item" id="dragD"
>
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragD">Boston Cream Pie <br><a class="more" data-id="dragD"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sortable-item" id="dragE"
>
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragE">Banana Cake <br> <a class="more" data-id="dragE">More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sortable-item" id="dragF">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragF">Birthday Cake<br><a class="more" data-id="dragF">More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sortable-item" id="dragG">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragG">Brownies <br><a class="more" data-id="dragG"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sortable-item" id="dragH">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragH">Carrot Cake<br><a class="more" data-id="dragH"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragI">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragI">Cheese Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragI"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragJ">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragJ">Ice Cream Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragJ"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragK">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragK">Chiffon Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragK"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragL">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragL">Coconut Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragL"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragM">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragM">Blueberry Muffin<br><a class="more" data-id="dragM"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragN">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragN">Cupcakes <br><a class="more" data-id="dragN"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragO">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragO">Black forest Cake<br><a class="more" data-id="dragO"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragP">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragP">Ginger bread<br><a class="more" data-id="dragP"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragQ">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragQ">Gooey Butter Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragQ"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragR">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragR">Layer Cake<br><a class="more" data-id="dragR"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragS">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragS">Lemon Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragS"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>
                       <li class="sortable-item" id="dragT">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragT">Marble Cake<br><a class="more" data-id="dragT"
>More Info</a></div>

                        <div class="blue">Third Level C</div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sortable-item" data-price="2.99" id="dragU">
                        <div class="red" data-id="dragU">Molten Chocolate Cake <br><a class="more" data-id="dragU"
>More Info</a></div>
                        <div class="green">Second Level D</div>
                        <div class="blue">Third Level D<br>
                            <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1">
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="Ab12">
                        <input type="hidden" class="extendedPrice" value="2.99">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="column left"> &nbsp;
                <div class="green" id="dragAmore"> <img src="images/chocolate-chip.jpg" alt="Cookie" width="150" height="150"> 
                    <p>Cookies made with love and served best with a glass of cold milk just like your grannies cookies.</p><br><a data-id="dragA">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragBmore"><img src="images/angelcake.jpg" alt="Angel" width="150" height="150">
                    <p>Try Germanys famous apple cake here in your neighbourhood! Apples used are freshly picked organic apples gotten from our local farmers.</p><br><a data-id="dragB">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragCmore"><img src="images/Applecake.jpg" alt="Pie" width="150" height="150">
                    <p>Try Germanys famous apple cake here in your neighbourhood! Apples used are freshly picked organic apples gotten from our local farmers.</p><br><a data-id="dragC" >Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragDmore"><img src="images/bostonpie.jpg" alt="Pie" width="150" height="150"><p>There was boston pizza and now theres Boston Pie which is even better! Make sure to try it.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragD">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragEmore"> <img src="images/bananacake.jpg" alt="Pie" width="150" height="150">
                    <p>Best had with tea or coffee. It has a strong taste of banana and sugar. This is one of my personal favorites!</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragE">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragFmore"><img src="images/birthday.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>We have a WIDE selection of birthday cakes ready to go and the option to customize your cake on order. We also have a wide variety of flavours.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragF">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragGmore"><img src="images/brownies.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Who doesn't love chocolaty brownies made from scratch and filled with goodness?</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragG">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragHmore"><img src="images/carrotcake.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>We all know carrots are good for our eyes but we may not all necessarily like eating plain carrots but we all sure do love cake!</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragH">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragImore"><img src="images/cheesecake.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>What you get when you combine the two best things, cheese and cake! Also comes with strawberries and any other fruit you'd prefer.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragI">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragJmore"><img src="images/icecream.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Ice cream cake is definetly my favourite thing! Ice cream and cake combined to make something so beautiful.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragJ">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragKmore"><img src="images/chiffon.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Light, airy cake made with vegetable oil, eggs, sugar, flour</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragK">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragLmore"><img src="images/coconut.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>A popular dessert in the Southern region of the United States. It is a cake frosted with a white frosting and covered in coconut flakes.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragL">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragMmore"><img src="images/blueberrymuffin.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Have this with tea or coffee! Its sure to be a great treat!</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragM">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragNmore"><img src="images/cupcakes.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>A small cake with various ingredients, usually topped with icing</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragN">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragOmore"><img src="images/blackforest.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Cherries, kirsch, and chocolate</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragO">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragPmore"><img src="images/gingerbread.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Gingerbread men made with ginger.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragP">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragQmore"><img src="images/gooey.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Originated from the US and filled with butter goodies.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragQ">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragRmore"><img src="images/layercake.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Egg yolk, sugar, butter, flour</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragR">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragSmore"><img src="images/lemoncake.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Made with fresh lemon and perfect to have with a cup of tea.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragS">Close</a></div>

                   <div class="green" id="dragTmore"><img src="images/marble.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                       <p>Vanilla, coffee, and/or chocolate</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragT">Close</a></div>

                <div class="green" id="dragUmore"><img src="images/molten.jpg" alt="Pie" width="200" height="150">
                    <p>Also known as lava cake is a popular dessert that combines the elements of a flourless chocolate cake (sometimes called a "chocolate decadence" cake) and a soufflé. Some other names used are "chocolate fondant", "chocolate moelleux", and "chocolate lava" cake.</p>
                    <br><a data-id="dragU">Close</a></div>

            </div>

            <form method="post" action="submit_cart.php">
                <div class="column left">
                    <ul class="sortable-list list3">

                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Checkout">
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>


        <!--
        <div class="ui-widget-content draggable red" data-top="" data-left"">
            <p>Drag me around <a data-id="draggable">Destroy or other action</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-widget-content draggable green" data-top="" data-left"">
            <p>Drag me around <a data-id="draggable">Destroy or other action</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-widget-content draggable blue" data-top="" data-left"">
            <p>Drag me around <a data-id="draggable">Destroy or other action</a></p>
        </div>


        <div id="container">

        </div>
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".more").click(
            function () {
//alert("bang clicked");
                var li = $(this).parents("li:first");
                var dragObjectId = $(this).parents("li:first").attr("data-id");
                $(li).slideUp("fast");
                var more = "#" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "more";
                $(more).slideDown("fast");
            }
        );

    $(".green a").click(
            function () {
                var li = $(this).parents("li:first");
                var dragObjectId = $(this).parents("li:first").attr("data-id");
                $(li).slideDown("fast");
                var more = "#" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "more";
                $(more).slideUp("fast");
                var close = "#" + $(this).attr("data-id");
                $(close).attr("style","position: static");
            }
        );



        $('#example-1-2 .sortable-list').sortable({
            connectWith: '#example-1-2 .sortable-list'
        });

        $(".draggable").draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#container"
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing both jquery and jquery-ui script references in your fiddle.
Adding them in gives you the draggable capability you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/9974/

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#container"
        });
```

(There are no changes to this code, just I am required to include code when linking to a fiddle)

I don't see anything in your script using your data-price attribute, so how are you trying to total?

Comment: left panel of the fiddle, references to jquery (under Frameworks & Extensions) and jquery-ui (external Resources)

Comment: How can i get that on my HTML

Comment: to your `<head>` tag add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and below that `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`